# How can i copy dependencies from external folder java

Tags: java, maven

How can i copy dependencies from an /lib folder in the same jar directory(not build directory), i was using this:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>../lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I'm getting ErrorNoClassFound,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/objects/Object2ObjectLinkedOpenHashMap
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:133) ~[patched.jar:git-PaperSpigot-"4c7641d"]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:331) ~[patched.jar:git-PaperSpigot-"4c7641d"]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:254) [patched.jar:git-PaperSpigot-"4c7641d"]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:293) [patched.jar:git-PaperSpigot-"4c7641d"]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:202) [patched.jar:git-PaperSpigot-"4c7641d"]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:563) [patched.jar:git-PaperSpigot-"4c7641d"]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_281]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/objects/Object2ObjectLinkedOpenHashMap
```

File manager:
[Image of how jar path and lib folder looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkjfQ.png)

Comment: So, how do you run the JAR? Did you correctly specify the lib folder to be on the classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand OK now, that exception throws when you try to execute the generated jar. If that is the case, your maven-dependency-plugin looks fine but maybe you are missing to add lib folder name to the classpath of the generated jar:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default-jar</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>jar</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <configuration>
        <finalName>${jar.name}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>  
            <mainClass>com.example.main.MainClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </plugin>
```

${jar.name} and ${project.version} are previously defined variables that you can replace  with the desired name for your jar. And com.example.main.MainClass is just an example that you have to replace with your Main class.

Answer (score 0):

There exist multiple ways to add local jar files to a Maven project below I show you 2:

1.Adding directly the dependency as system scope:

Assuming that the JAR is located in <PROJECT_ROOT_FOLDER>/lib add the dependency in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.example.examples</groupId>
  <artifactId>example-jar</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/your_jar.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

2.Install the JAR into a local Maven repository

Use this for example:

```
mvn install:install-file –Dfile=C:\jar_directory\your_jar.jar -DgroupId=com.example.test -DartifactId=example-jar -Dversion=1.0
```

Next, add the dependency to your Maven project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.example.examples</groupId>
  <artifactId>example-jar</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am not in look for a way to add local jar to a Maven Project, i am in look for a way to use my dependencies, and not build them into the jar, but to use them on a lib folder where my project jar is located, and then that way i can have an  project jar with a reduced size, do you have an idea how to?

Comment: Sorry, I understad now. I posted another answer below.